# Apache Ignite: How to use IgniteCache to prevent execution of functionality on all the Nodes in the Cluster?

Tags: locking, cluster-computing, ignite

I have an application that runs on multiple Nodes and processes requests from an outside system ( via load balancing ). The ProcessMethod uses Data that's loaded into the Ignite Cache ( RefCache ). Requests may come at any time and in significant volumes ( > 1000), although it could be single request too. At the same time application has an ability to Reload data in my cache(RefCache) either on-demand or at the scheduled time. The requirements are :

1. Can't process outside Requests while (re)loading data into the IgniteCache
2. Can't reload the IgniteCache while processing the requests from the outside system.

I came up with the solution of having a separate Ignite Cache and keeping a RequestCounter there :

```
private void processMethod(){
IgniteCache counterCache = cacheService.getCache("myCounterCache"); // cacheService is wrapper
Integer counter = counterCache.get(counterCacheKey);
if(counter == null )
    counter = 1;
else 
    counter++;


counter.put(counterCacheKey, counter);
  ...
  some processing
  ...

Lock lock = IgniteCache.lock(counterCacheKey); //prevent update from other nodes
try{
     counter = counterCache.get(counterCacheKey);
     counterCache.put(counterCacheKey, counter - 1)
}
finally{
    lock.unlock();
}

}
```

At the same time there could be a request to Reload data in the RefCache

```
public void reloadCache(){

        IgniteCache counterCache = cacheService.getCache("myCounterCache"); 
        IgniteCache refDataCache = cacheService.getCache("myRefDataCache"); 

        Integer counter = counterCache.get(counterCacheKey);

        if ( counter == null || counter == 0 ){
          startRefDataCacheReload();
          refDataCache.put(cacheLoadedKey, false);
        }
        ....
        loading data into IgniteRefCache
        ....
        
        refDataCache.put(cacheLoadedKey, true);
}
```

Code snippets are a surdo-code rather than an actual code. I want to understand whether my approach is correct. I clearly see some shortcomings here:

1. ProcessingRequest came in and Counter imcremented to 1
2. Cache Reload Request came in but RefCache is not getting reloaded because the Counter > 0; CacheReload goes to sleep;
3. Another Processing Request comes in and at that time 1 ProcessingRequest finished and opened the gate to reload RefCache.
4. Before I prevent second ProcessingRequest to start processing it increments the Counter and continues while I am reloading RefCache.

The possibility of this happening is extremely low, however I have to account for all the situations

Comment: It's unclear what can trigger cache reload. Is it performed by demand? E.g. by explicit command from admin user or something like that.

Should external request wait until reload finished or they should return with fail/wait response?

I guess that you should try to implement some king of cache proxy wrapper that will implement gate logic (or circuit breaker logic during cache reload). And you can try to exploit distributed components available out of the box:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/countdownlatch
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-locks